# Django: 'Thoughts' object has no attribute 'choice_set' - Trouble accessing a choice set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In my model I define a Thoughts and Comments model. One thought has many Comments as so:

```
class Thoughts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    thought = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    original_post = models.ForeignKey(Thoughts, default=0)
```

On my site, when you go to view a thought, I want all of the comments to appear. It is my understanding that you can use choice_set to access attributes via one-to-many relationship. Here's my view:

```
def thought(request, thought_num):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            c = Comments.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                comment=form.cleaned_data['comment'])
            c.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    get_post = Thoughts.objects.get(pk=thought_num)
    comments = get_post.choice_set.all()
    return render(request, 'thought.html', {'form': form, 'comment':comments,})
```

In these lines, I attempt to access all comments related to a particular thought in order to print them in my template.

```
    get_post = Thoughts.objects.get(pk=thought_num)
    comments = get_post.choice_set.all()
```

When I access the page that should display the comments, I get this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'Thoughts' object has no attribute 'choice_set'
```

Perhaps I am missing something, I am not sure. I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks for your time

Comment: Since your model is called `Comments`, the `related_name` would be called `comments_set`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Comment: `original_post = models.ForeignKey(Thoughts, default=0, related_name='choice_set')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all the Comments related to a Thought. You can do the following:

`Thoughts.objects.get(pk=thought_num).comments_set.all()`

If you would like to override the default related_name ("comments_set"). You can do the following:
`original_post = models.ForeignKey(Thoughts, default=0, related_name='choice_set')`

Answer (score 0):

When you make a ForeignKey the default related name becomes the lower case name of the current class + "_set" so for your project should be:

```
get_post = Thoughts.objects.get(pk=thought_num)
comments = get_post.comments_set.all()
```

Or you could even create a custom related name instead of the default:

```
class Thoughts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    thought = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    class Thoughts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    thought = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    original_post = models.ForeignKey(Thoughts, default=0, related_name='comments')
```

so you can get your comments like this:

```
get_post = Thoughts.objects.get(pk=thought_num)
comments = get_post.comments.all()
```